# How can I get a windows server to collate and email 4 daily reports/graphs for server performance

Tags: windows, performance-monitoring

I run a windows 2008 webserver and would like to setup the most basic performance monitoring in the world.

What i would like is:

1. a plot of ASP.Net request time for each w3wp process for a 24hour period
2. a plot of CPU% utilisation for each w3wp process for a 24hour period
3. a plot of Memory utilisation for each w3wp process for a 24hour period
4. a plot of network utilisation for each w3wp process for a 24hour period
5. a plot of disk utilisation for each w3wp process for a 24hour period

I would these plots to be emailed to me each morning.

Anybody know what is the simplest way to set this up?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Glyn